# Ajax.Actionlink opens in a new page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have a partial view that needs to get loaded between two div but when the ajax.actionlink is invoked it open the content in the partial view in a new browser window. I use UpdateTargetId = "ajaxReplace"

Regards

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Did you include/reference all the necessary javascript files?

You say you use MVC 3.

If you have `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled` then you'll need:

- jQuery
- jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js

if you also use client side validation, you'll need;

- jquery.validate.js
- jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js

These files can all be found when you create a new MVC3 project.

Comment: Yes both MicrosoftAjax.debug,js and MicrosoftMvcAjax.debug.js

Comment: Which version of MVC are you using? In MVC 3 with onubtrusive javascript, these files are not in use anymore. It seems like your page does an ordinary form POST and not a javascript form post.

Comment: Then you'll probably need at least jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js and if you use client side validation you'll also need jquery.validate.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js

Answer (score 1):

```
[OutputCache(Duration=0)]
```

on the controller method.  I had this with an AJAX.ActionResult which worked well in FF but not in IE8.  IE8 must send back some stuff that lets the caching engine just return the value.